# How to make quintiles in sas with BRR replicated weight

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with 500 BRR replicate weights. I want to create quintiles for my continuous variable 'Var1' using weighted data.

With unweighted data, I use PROC RANK and specify groups=5. However, I'm uncertain how to apply this method to weighted data. I saw there is a 'quantile=' function in proc surveymeans, not sue how to make quintiles.
Thanks

Comment: Show a small sample datasets, perhaps with just 10 observations that you can put into 3 groups and show what result you would want from that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.